# 301 redirect but let a certain URL through

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have this code:

```
Redirect 301 /forums/ http://www.example.com
```

So anything that is example.com/forums goes to site.com but I have one set of pagination that goes to example.com/forums/discussions/....

With my code it messes everything up, so how can I set the redirect to only apply to just /forums/ and let forums/discussions continue through like normal?

Comment: You can't. redirect is a "parent" match, and you can't exempt "children" from it. You'll have to use mod_rewrite to get that kind of control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `RedirectMatch` instead of `Redirect` directive that gives us regex power.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/forums/(?!discussions) http://www.example.com
```

`(?!discussions)` is negative lookahead to fail this rule if request URI is `/forums/discussions`